# Hidden sidebar: how can I disable popping up icons?

Tags: unity, launcher

I set my Unity sidebar to hidden. Great!

However, I am still seeing icons popping out which terribly annoys me.

How can I disable this behaviour?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The described behavior is done by design and so, the default and expected behavior. There is a possibility to avoid the popping up of those icons using the `unity-tweak-tool`. You can install the tool by executing `sudo apt install unity-tweak-tool`. Open Unity Tweak Tool from the dash  and switch the Icons settings of Urgent animation and Launch animation to **No animation**.

[image]

Now the little caveat : I have tested it and mostly it works as expected, but sometimes it didn't ... (because as mentioned before, it is not the default behavior being intended by the design team). But that might be due to the fact that I switched the settings too often during the testing phase. When you just keep the changed settings and restart the session, it also might work persistently.

Comment: But indeed you are right. It doesn't work for all applications. :-( Should I file a bug report despite this is not the intended behaviour by the developers?

Comment: @orschiro Why not ? I suggest to report it to the Unity Tweak Tool team ... they implemented the option. :) Here is the link to the Unity Tweak Tool team on Launchpad -> https://launchpad.net/unity-tweak-tool

Comment: [Bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity-tweak-tool/+bug/1661585)

Comment: @orschiro I confirmed the bug for you to rise up the importance. Please add some more details to the bug report, for example the fact that it works properly in some cases and in others (sometimes) not ... because the more information the team gets - the higher the chances are, that they are able to fix the issue soon. :)

Comment: @orschiro I talked about your problem with one of the UTT team members, he will investigate the issue. :)

Comment: Wow, that's kind. Thank you for your efforts! I will add some more observations to the bug report. :-)

Comment: @orschiro You're welcome ! :) I always try my best (when I can)  to contribute something positive in order to fix problems and improve ubuntu experience generally. This includes providing working solutions in my answers and helping to fix bugs when possible. :)